# UpdateAll is not working with bigint() fields

Tags: cakephp

I'm quite new to CakePHP and have an issue. I'm trying to update one field in a row with this:

```
$options = array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $_POST['userid']));
$user = $this->User->find('first', $options);

$currentpoint = $user['User']['point'];
$correctanswerpoint = Configure::read('CORRECT_SYSTEMANSWER_POINT');
$newpoint = $currentpoint + $correctanswerpoint;

$this->User->updateAll(array('User.point'=>$newpoint), array('User.id'=>$_POST['userid']));
```

There are no errors, but the field point (bigint(20)) is not being updated. I've changed the field to update to another one in the same row which is of smallint type and the update goes through fine.

My debugging log seems to show that the SQL query is ok too:

```
            [query] => UPDATE `askyoode_askyoo`.`users` AS `User` LEFT JOIN `askyoode_askyoo`.`countries` AS `Country` ON (`User`.`country_id` = `Country`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `askyoode_askyoo`.`accesstypes` AS `Accesstype` ON (`User`.`accesstype_id` = `Accesstype`.`id`) SET `User`.`point` = 57  WHERE `User`.`id` = 124
            [params] => Array
                (
                )

            [affected] => 1
            [numRows] => 1
            [took] => 12
        )
```

And manually running the same SQL statement in MySQL works. Been tearing out my hair for the whole day trying to resolve this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: I had this problem
I installed 64 bits Wamp then 
The problem was solved.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually on Linux, not sure if that's the problem. I actually tried changing the MySQL column to an INT and it also fails to update. But there are some other INT columns that will update without problems.

Comment: Finally found the problem. It was because that field was set to cachecount in the Model. Wasn't aware what the previous developer did!